# For what values of $k$ this matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $D_{k}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}k&2&k&3k\\1&0&1&3\\4&0&k&12\\2&k&2&k\end{array}\right]$. For what values of $k$ this matrix is invertible?

There is a property that says if the rank of a matrix is equal to the number of its lines/columns (since it's a square matrix), then the matrix is invertible.

So one needs to find the echelon form of the matrix. In this case:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}k&2&k&3k\\1&0&1&3\\4&0&k&12\\2&k&2&k\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow{L_{1}\leftrightarrow L_{2}}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1&3\\k&2&k&3k\\4&0&k&12\\2&k&2&k\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow{L_{3}=L_{3}-4L_{1}}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1&3\\k&2&k&3k\\0&0&k-4&0\\2&k&2&k\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow{L_{4}=L_{4}-2L_{1}}$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1&3\\k&2&k&3k\\0&0&k-4&0\\0&k&0&k-6\end{array}\right]$$

Now, in order to get the echelon form, $k=0$ and $k\neq4$ and $k \neq6$. The conclusion is that the matrix $D_{k}$ is invertible for $k=0$. But I've checked with $k=5$ and the matrix $D_{5}$ is also invertible.

What is wrong in my conclusion? Thanks.

Comment: Have you studied determinants already?

Comment: @DonAntonio, no I didn't.

Comment: What makes you suspect that there are only few values of k for which this matrix is invertible. I just checked it is invertible for k = pi You essentially found the values for k for which it is NOT invertible by doing row operations, which is great.

Comment: Nothing restrains you from doing $L_2=L_2-kL_1$ (what an ugly notation!) in the last matrix. What you can't do is multiplying a row by a quantity depending on $k$.

Comment: You could also compute the determinant by expanding along the second column (which contains only two non-zeroes).  Oops, I missed your comment that you haven't studied determinants.  The matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k \neq4 $ and $k \neq 6$, you can still get row-echelon form even if $k \neq 0$.. In your last matrix, subtract $k$ times the first row from the second row. Then subtract $k/2$ times the second row from the fourth row. This will give you row-echelon form and you can infer when the matrix is invertible accordingly. You should get a matrix that just has $1,2,k-4,k-6$ on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else below the diagonal.

Comment: So, my mistake was that the last matrix was not in the echelon form. I didn't know that I could make row operations using the $k$ factor.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&3\\k&2&k&3k\\4&0&k&12\\2&k&2&k\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&3\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&k-4&0\\0&k&0&k-6\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&3\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&k-4&0\\0&0&0&k-6\end{pmatrix}$$

The above shows the matrix's invertible unless $\;k=4,6\;$